# How to replace an empty value of a particular column with a certain value in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a CSV file like this for example

| id | name | item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | bread | 67 |
| 2 | Danny | butter |  |
| 3 | Elle | cheese |  |
| 4 | Mark | coffee | 9 |

I want to replace empty Qty values with 0. I have tried :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df.loc[df['Qty'] =='','Qty']=0
```

But this is not replacing empty values. Any suggestions to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df['Qty']=df['Qty'].fillna('0').astype(int)
```

Input `Sample.csv`

```
id,name,item,Qty
1,Sta,bread,67
2,Danny,butter,
3,Elle,cheese,
4,Mark,coffee,9
```

Output

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
print(df)
   id   name    item   Qty
0   1    Sta   bread  67.0
1   2  Danny  butter   NaN
2   3   Elle  cheese   NaN
3   4   Mark  coffee   9.0
df['Qty']=df['Qty'].fillna('0').astype(int)
print(df)
   id   name    item Qty
0   1    Sta   bread  67
1   2  Danny  butter   0
2   3   Elle  cheese   0
3   4   Mark  coffee   9
```

Comment: They are not `NaNs`, they're empty strings

Comment: this replaces all Qty as 0

Comment: Ah! But there were no values. Doesn't missing value mean `NaN`? @U11-Forward

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy No they mean `''`

Comment: But I copy pasted the OPs sample data in a csv. And when I print ,its giving `NaN` for those missing values.@U11-Forward

Comment: @AtomStore, For me, it just replaces for missing values. Updated the output

Comment: I have edited the answer Mr Arun's answer is right but need to convert it into integer type. Please upvote and accept if it works.

Comment: I have edited to convert the output as an integer. Please check the updated answer @AtomStore. Btw you are the one who should accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `replace`:

```
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].replace('', 0).astype(int)
```

So the full code would be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].replace('', 0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Comment: Your code replaces like 67.0 ,9.0 in the qty field but not the empty values

Comment: @AtomStore What do you mean?

Comment: it replaces 67 with 67.0, 9 with 9.0 not empty values with 0

Comment: @AtomStore I edited my answer, please upvote and accept if it works

Comment: Since there are empty values, it raises a ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer